# AJAX: Having trouble retrieving queryset from server and appending to select options

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, ajax, django

I am able to send the value of the input field with the id datepicker to the server. And with this in the view I filter the time slot by the ones that occur on the same date.

Where I am having difficulties is sending this queryset to the browser and then appending this to the options.

I'm still relatively new to javascript I apologize if this is a newb question. I definitely appreciate any feedback!

My View:

```
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_date = request.POST['selected_date']
        slots_on_day = Calendar.objects.filter(date=selected_date)

        return HttpResponse(slots_on_day)
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        document.getElementById("display_slots").style.display ="block";

          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data:  {
                'selected_date':$('#datepicker').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
              },
              success: function(resp){
                for (var i=0; i < resp['slots_on_day'].length;++i){
                  addOption(
                    document.getElementById("display_slots"), resp['slots_on_day'][i], resp['slots_on_day'][i]);
                }
              }
          });

      });
    });
```

Notes:  the id=datepicker field triggers the ajax event. I then want to receive the response from the server and append the options to the input with the id=display_slots

Error:

```
TypeError: resp.slots_on_day is undefined
```

**Updated ajax success**

```
success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                        $('select[name=display_slots]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the response `resp`. What structure is the data being given in?

Comment: @NewToJS So does that basically mean what is the slots_on_day? It is... <QuerySet [<Calendar: 2018-03-05 | 08:00:00 - 10:00:00>, <Calendar: 2018-03-05 | 08:00:00 - 10:00:00>, <Calendar: 2018-03-05 | 10:00:00 - 12:00:00>, <Calendar: 2018-03-05 | 10:00:00 - 12:00:00>]>.........These are string representations of an object

Comment: What do you see if you place `console.log(resp);` in the `ajax` **success** function?

Comment: @NewToJS O! It prints the string representation of the objects contained in slots_on_day. But then on the next line it also prints TypeError: resp.slots_on_day is undefined

Comment: 2018-03-05 | 08:00:00 - 10:00:002018-03-05 | 08:00:00 - 10:00:002018-03-05 | 10:00:00 - 12:00:002018-03-05 | 10:00:00 - 12:00:00

Comment: You are sending queryset in ajax reponse and javascript will not understand what is this. So you need to response data from backend in JSON structure that you want to use in frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_date = request.POST['selected_date']
        slots_on_day = Calendar.objects.filter(date=selected_date)
        data = []
        for cal in slots_on_day:
            data.append(model_to_dict(cal))
        return JsonResponse(status=200, data={'slots_on_day':data})
```

It'll send JSON response in frontend and now you can use this data as you want to use. I think, It'll work with your current ajax success method code

Comment: Thanks! If I print the data variable in the view I get: [{'id': 41, 'date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 5), 'timeslot_A': datetime.time(8, 0), 'timeslot_B': datetime.time(10, 0), 'booked': False},

Comment: I have updated the javascript code as well. In the display_slots select I just get one option at the moment with the words [object, Object],  [object, Object],  [object, Object],

Comment: $.each(data['slots_on_day'], function(key, value){
                        $('select[name=display_slots]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value +'</option>');
                    });

You have to key in data var in success method account to backedn response

Comment: Now for the values of the options theyre numbered from 0 and increment by 1. And for the text for all of them the output is [object Object]

Comment: I Solved it all. Thank you so very much.